# Acer PC won't boot from CDRom after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu, acer

Thanks for taking the time to read my question! :)

I have a very old ACER PC (I think it was bought in 2005) and I installed ubuntu replacing windows XP which is outdated. I have recently experienced problems trying to install kali on it and my impression is that this is because the computer has non-PAE CPU. I found a possible solution that would require to install lubuntu first and then do some other tricks etc but when I try to install lubuntu from the DVDROM drive, it doesn't do it and keeps logging back to ubuntu. Checked the CD/DVD input and it works fine. Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Does any other CD/DVD boot on that machine? What is the output of `lsb_release --short`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "Boot From CD-ROM" is a choice your computer makes in BIOS, so you'l have to hit <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> when rebooting and find the `Boot Order` setting. Not a Ubuntu problem.